# Aumenta tamanho da fonte no python e como diminui o número de casas decimais?

Tags: python

```
print ('Área da seção transversal:',Acf,'m^2 \n')
print ('Velocidade média:',Vf,'m/s \n')
print ('Número de reynolds:',Re_f,'[adimensional] \n')
print ('Número de nusselt:',Nuf,'[adimensional] \n')
print ('Coeficiente de troca de calor por convecção:',hf,'W/m^2 K \n')
print ('Capacidade térmica:',Cf,'kW/K \n')
```

> Área da seção transversal: 1.2566370614359172e-05 m^2
>
> Velocidade média: 7.976571864194266 m/s
>
> Número de reynolds: 23823.25541992501 [adimensional]
>
> Número de nusselt: 15.622791714636927 [adimensional]
>
> Coeficiente de troca de calor por convecção: 2348.2618226270765 W/m^2
>   K
>
> Capacidade térmica: 0.41812800000000006 kW/K

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075128/python-print-all-floats-to-2-decimal-places-in-output acredito que isso responda sua dúvida na questão de casas decimais.

Answer (score 4):

## tamanho da fonte

Aumentar o tamanho da fonte não é possível para programas com saída no terminal (com print): Isso faz parte das configurações do seu terminal - que é um programa que o seu programa em Python, e o executável da linguagem Python em si, só utiliza, ele não é "dono" do terminal.

Programas que interagem com o "mundo" com print e input só vem três "fluxos de dados", que são os (pseudo) arquivos sys.stdin, sys.stdout e sys.stderr - tudo o que o print faz é escrever caracteres nesses arquivos.

Em sistemas operacionais que não são o Windows, ou, com alguma configuração no Windows, algumas sequências de caracteres permitem a configuração de cores de frente e fundo, bem como posicionamento do texto nos terminais - (veja https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_escape_ANSI ), mas não há sequências para alterar o tamanho da fonte.

Se você deseja uma saída mais amigável, talvez como parte do "acabamento" para entregar um aplicativo para uso por outros usuários, a única saída é criar um programa que use outro tipo de interface que não o terminal. Pode ser um programa com uma interface Web - nesse caso você poderia usar um micro-framework como o "[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)",  ou um programa que funcione com uma janela gráfica diretamente - nesse caso você pode usar o "[tkinter](https://www.qt.io/qt-for-python)", que acompanha a instalação do Python no Windows, ou um toolkit gráfico como o "[Qt](https://www.qt.io/qt-for-python)".

## Limitar casas decimais

Isso é mais simples - o problema é que você está usando o `print` de uma forma bem rudimentar - separando tudo o que quer imprimir por ",", e delimitando cada substring por aspas.

O uso mais comum é usar as capacidades de formatação de string do Python e compor uma única string com o texto e dados, já formatados, que você deseja imprimir, e então chamar o `print` com essa string. No caso do programa ter sido alterado para uma janela gráfica, ou uma saída pra Web, a mesma string pode ser utilizada, só não é passada para o print.

A partir do Python 3.6, a forma recomendada de compor strings com textos e dados formatados é com o uso das "f-strings" - são strings que tem o prefixo `f"` ou `f'` - ou seja, a letra "f" antes das aspas iniciais. Dentro dessas strings, qualquer expressão que apareça entre chaves (`{ }`)  é tratada como código Python (por exemplo, um nome de variável é substituído pelo seu valor). E mais ainda, antes de fechar a chave, depois da expressão desejada pode-se fazer uso de uma "mini linguagem de formatação", que permite coisas como justificar o texto ou controlar o numero de casas decimais de um número.

A mini-linguagem é complicada, mas indo a parte que interessa - você pode escrever seu `print` assim:

```
print(f'Coeficiente de troca de calor por convecção: {hf:0.04f} W/m² K')
```

Assim, como explicado - dentro da mesma string, iniciada com o prefixo `f`, o nome `hf` usado dentro das chaves vai ser trocado pelo valor da variável, e a sequência `:0.04f` indica que o valor deve ser tratado como um ponto flutuante, e devem ser impressos 4 números depois do ponto decimal, preenchidos com "0" se houver menos casas decimais que isso.

A referência completa da mini-linguagem de formatação é a documentada para o método `format` das strings (que deve ser usado nas versões anteriores a 3.6 do Python, que ainda não tinham as f-strings)  - https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

(também troquei o ^2 pelo caractére unicode "²" - vai funcionar na maior parte dos terminais - mas talvez não no terminal padrão do Windows).

## Jupyter notebook

Num uso simples, o Jupyter notebook emula o comportamento de sys.stdin, sys.sdout, para que o print e input funcionem. Usando as funções normais do Python não é possível ter mais controle sobre a saída do que num terminal. A diferença maior é que ao contrário de um terminal do Windows, ele permite algumas ANSI sequences, em particular para troca de cor. (Exemplo curto está no comentário abaixo).

No entanto o jupyter notebook tem algumas categorias de objetos que permitem mais controle da saída, e interação com o browser direto sim - que pemrmitem, no limite o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação gráfica completa dentro do notebook.

No entanto, fazer isso é umas duas ordens de grandeza mais complicado do que simplesmente usar "print" e "input".  A forma mais direta parece ser criar um objeto que vai ser um "widget" de saída, e, usando esse "widget" num comando `with` do Python, é possível redirecionar a saída do print para ele. O Widget por outro lado pode ter algumas das características de impressão personalizadas - pode ter borda e cor do texto específicados em CSS. Não consegui, no entanto, alterar justamente o *tamanho da fonte*: a propriedade "font-size" é ignorada no layout do widget.

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display

out = widgets.Output(layout={"color":"red", 'border': '1px solid blue', 'font-size': '200%'})

display(out)
with(out):
    print(f"Alô mundo. Formatando número: {3.210002:0.02f}")
```

Documentação dos widgets: 
https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Output%20Widget.html

Comment: Para fazer esse código eu estou utilizando o Jupyter  Notebook, ainda sou iniciante nessa área de programação e essas informações vão ajudar bastante. Sobre aumentar a fonte de saída do print era para poder visualizar melhor os resultados na área de resultados desse programa, no Jupyter seria possível aumentar o tamanho da fonte das strings na saída?

Comment: Não - do ponto de vista do Python, o jupyter também funciona como um terminal - a parte que fica no navegador usa CSS e HTML, claro, mas isso fica dentro do código do próprio jupyter - um programa, ou código emPython pra rodar dentro dos notebooks não tem acesso aos mesmos.
No entanto, o jupyter notebook implementa de forma limitadas as ANSI sequences que eu citei - então, imprimindo-se a sequência "<ESC>[<código-de-cor>m" é possível ter a saída do print colorida no notebook: `print("\x1b[31malo")` - imprime "alô" em vermelho.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta para incluir algumas considerações sobre o jupyter.